# SAS format to append text to character variable

Tags: sas

Is it possible to create a SAS format that appends text to the end of a character variable? I have a comment variable with a lot of text. Ideally I would like to cut off the text at at certain point and add "..." to the end. I know I could create a new variable to accomplish this, but I would like this to be a format I can apply. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can build this into a format.

I think you could easily do:

```
data want;
set have;
newcomment = ifc(length(comment) le 300, comment, substr(comment,1,300)||'...');
run;
```

I don't think you can really get it much better than that.  You can't write a `PICTURE` format for character variables, unfortunately, as far as I know (which is what you're asking for).

(`IFC` returns a character value based on the boolean value of the first argument, like Excel's IF.)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, building on what @Joe mentioned above, is to use a view:

```
proc sql;
create view want_view as 
select
a.SomeVar
,case 
 when length(a.comment) <=300 then a.comment
 else substr(a.comment,1,300)||'...')
end as truncated_comment length = 303
from have as a;
quit;
```

The advantage of using a view in this case is that

1. You get Format-like capability
2. You do not need to create a new column
3. If you need to investigate a column that has been truncated at 300 bytes - you still have access to the un-truncated comment in the physical table.
4. The view does not cost you disk space.

Comment: I don't know a lot about proc sql, but wouldn't truncated_comment be a new variable?

Comment: @user2777799: That is correct. truncated_comment is a new variable. But the trick is in the line which creates the view "create view want_view". Inside the view you can either make both the variables available or just the truncated one. As I mentioned, even though you are creating a new variable the view itself does not take up any disk space.